# Как отсортировать массив объектов, чтобы объединить все объекты с определенным ключом? /JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть масcив вида:

```
 [{
    "def": 900,
    "from": 100000,
    "before": 199999,
  },
  {
    "def": 900,
    "from": 200000,
    "before": 299999,
  },
  {
    "def": 901,
    "from": 111111,
    "before": 222222,
  } ...]
```

Как его отсортировать по ключу def, чтобы получить только уникальные def, но со всеми значениями from и before, т.е. из них получить массив из значений всех таких объектов.

Получиться должен массив:

```
  [{
    "def": 900,
    "from": [100000, 200000, ...]
    "before": [199999, 299999, ...]
  },
  {
    "def": 901,
    "from": [111111, 222222, ...]
    "before": [222222, 333333, ...]
  }, ...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так думаю.

1. Сортируете по ключу def, если равны то по from если равны то по before
2. reduce по массиву и строим искомый объект. Если существует то добавляем новый элемет в существующий. Если нет его в результате то добавляем новый предварительно подготовивв объект

```js
let array = [{
    "def": 900,
    "from": 1000000,
    "before": 199999,
  },
  {
    "def": 900,
    "from": 200000,
    "before": 299999,
  },
  {
    "def": 901,
    "from": 111111,
    "before": 222222,
  }];
  
let result = array
   .sort((a, b)=> a.def != b.def? a.def - b.def: a.from != b.from? a.from - b.from: a.before - b.before)
   .reduce( (acc, item) => { 
    let key = acc.find(i => i.def == item.def); 
    if (key != null) {
      key.from.push(item.from);  
      key.before.push(item.before);  
    } else {
      acc.push({def: item.def, from: [item.from], before: [item.before]});
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли :)

Answer (score 1):

вам не отсортировать надо, а пересобрать, т.е. вам надо

1. пройти по всем элементам списка
2. записывать данные как в словарь

2.1) если ключ `def` уже существует, то добавлять записи в поля `from` и `before`,

2.2) если ключ `def` не существует, то добавлять сразу всю структуру (с `def`, `from`, `before`)

кстати раз у вас `from`, `before` - это массивы, а не значения, то не лучше ли объединить данные в пары и записывать в виде

```
data: [[11, 22], [33, 44]]
```

и т.д. или как

```
data: [{'after': 11, 'before': 22}, {'after': 33, 'before': 44}]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли :)